# Google Tag Manager and dataLayer.push for eCommerce in Custom Code tag

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

Are you able to use the dataLayer.push() in the "Custom Code" tag in Google Tag Manager instead of putting the code directly in the template or page for eCommerce?  Or anything other dataLayer.push() event for that matter?

My plan is to use Javascript or jQuery to get the get the elements on the page to push data to the dataLayer.push() properties. I was wondering if anyone with more knowledge of the Google Tag Manager than I have ever done this or if it possible.

Something like the image below. Or does the dataLayer.push() event NEED to be  in an actual template or page on the site? Or would putting the dataLayer.push() code into a Custom HTML block cause issues with firing the tag?

[image]

Comment: Yes you can write javascript as "custom code" and do things like assign handlers which get called when events happen on your site, and then do pushes to the dataLayer from within the custom code.

Comment: @James,  thanks for the response.  I added an image of what I am asking about.  I didn't know if adding the dataLayer.push() event into Tag Manager would cause any issues.  My assumption would be no, because it is more or less like a FB pixel entered into the page. I just didn't know if this would mess up any data.  Of course have all my elements and values filled in via the JS. but this is just an example to see if it advisable or not a good idea.